# MYSQL - SImple database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I would like to develop a system, where user will get the data dynamically(what I mean dynamic is, without reloading pages, using AJAX.. but well, it does not matter much).

My situation is like this. I have this table, I called it "player", in this player table, I will store the player information like, player name, level, experience etc.

Each player can have different clothes, start from tops(shirts), bottoms, shoes, and hairstyle, and each player can have more than 1 tops, bottoms, shoes etc.

What I am hesitated or not very sure about is, how do you normally store the data? My current design is like this:

```
Player Table
===========================================================================================
id   |  name   | (others player's info)  |      wearing                   | tops | bottoms
===========================================================================================
  1  | player1 |                         | top=1;bottom=2;shoes=5;hair=8  | 1,2,3| 7,2,3


Tops Table
=====================
id  |  name   | etc...
=====================
 1  | t-shirt | ...
```

I am not sure if this design is good. If you are the database designer, how would you design the database? Or how you will store them?

Please advise. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: instead of putting the column "wearing" in, you should make a table that connects the 2 tables (players and clothes.)

You'd get

```
players
id name
1  player1

clotheTypes
1  top
2  bottom

clothes
id  name   type
1   shirt1 1
2   shirt2 1
3   pants1 2

wearing
playerId ClotheId
1        1
1        2
```

But please, do read the article taht @badcat shared!

edit: as requested, some hints:

You don't want this generally:

```
id name    computer
1  john    work, laptop, desktop, oldcomputer
```

Because you that should be in a seperate table. Now you can actually add, later on, the brand and speed of the computers: you can't the way you're doing it right now.

```
Person
id name
1  john

computer
id name    owner
1  work     1
2  laptop   1
3  desktop  1
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the design. I had a hard time understanding the normalization. I have been reading it for half-a-day :(
Is there any additional tips in database design? (like how to come up with the design like yours? Of course I need to understanding normalization at least up to 3rd level)

Comment: Basic tips would be: You do not want "comma seprated" values in a field -> that should be in a new table, and if you see double values in several rows (e.g. name, lastname, address), then that should also be in 1 table

Comment: Thats means, I should remove my tops columns in the "player" table? And create a table something like "player_top" table to store player's tops(shirts)?

Comment: well, it's hard to explain all, that's why I provided above example. I'll give you some more example of what you do not want, but it's a bit of a wide scope

Comment: Oh I forgot to tell you one thing. I used JSON (jquery to fetch data, dynamically), so when I select the player_tops table, I am gonna to have a huge list, I guess? I think I need to open a new question.

Comment: I just posted a question, do you mind take a look? its here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658044/php-json-passing-value-from-php-to

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are new to this.

Please read this article on Wikipedia about database normalization:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

---

Personally I would not do it like in the example above, because you'd have to update the players' table every time some T-Shirt is added or removed.

Comment: Yup, I have read normalization up to 3rd level. May I know, how will you design for my case above?

Comment: I have a question here, you said: " you'd have to update the players' table every time some T-Shirt is added or removed", but whenever the user add/remove clothes, I need to update some table right? (Based on @nanne answer, I still need to update "players_tops" table), so whats the differences??

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an additional tables for clothes, something like this:

**player**

```
id_player  //1
name       //Jhon
level      //6
experience //13
```

**player_cloth**

```
id_player   //1
id_clothe   //5
```

**cloth_types**

```
id_cloth    // 5
type        // hat
description // very warm
```

Once you have created the tables you need to relate this data, you only need the `id_player` value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is your design similar to nanne?

Comment: he has an extra table for clothes types, but yes, i would say it is similar, you must have read by now that there are several normalization levels, that is basically the difference.

Comment: I see. I am still in the middle of understanding normalization. May I know, in practices, up to which level should I normalize in database design?

Comment: That depends on your needs, the higher the normalization level does not mean that it is better. I usually go up to the second